# 2010 dodge ram 1500 reg./E-85

Tags: fuel-system, dodge, ram

I let my wife put gas in the car and she thought it was E-85. But she put eco-diesel gas (only) 5.00 dollars worth so my guess maybe 2 gallons now my truck smokes a lot and wants to shut off. I bought Techron, Put 1 in when it fist happened the 2nd after I put $25.OO worth of gas.

Will this fix it?

Please! Help!

What can I Do?

Answer (score 2):

Your not going to like the answer. Diesel is a thick oil as compared to gasoline. Fuel filters for the two are quite different. Your truck has a returnless fuel system with an integral fuel filter in the fuel pump module. The oil probably has contaminated the filer preventing normal flow of gasoline. Dropping and draining the tank will get you most of the way there. If you flush the fuel line from the rail to the tank while the tank is out would also help. If you can find the fuel filer as a separate unit then replace it but you may have to put a new fuel pump module in it. If you are still having problems then there might be diesel oil trapped in the rail and/or injectors. Pull and flush the rail. Flow test the injectors in a machine to make sure they are not plugged.

Comment: Diesel is not a thick oil. It is thin and non-viscous. The problems are that it kills octane, fouls spark plugs and harms catalytic converters. The tank can be drained without dropping it, or replacing the pump or filters.

Comment: @kmarsh Diesel is thicker than gasoline.